# Data validation for inline javascript

Tags: wp-head, sanitization

I try to save inline javascript(Google analytics code) in wp-options table. But i can't figure out what validation function i shall use.

I have tried esc_js when saving to the database. But i can't figure out what to use when i shall echo it in the head section.

Comment: `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` not work for you?

Comment: I submitted it as an answer so you can mark as solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` to prepare any data for database entry. These are native PHP functions, not wordpress functions, so they do not necessarily need to be hooked anywhere specific in the wordpress load to work.

Comment: I just discovered that the output when using stripslashes is like this: <script type=\\\\\\\"text/javascript\\\\\\\">
I tought stripslashes removed them?

Comment: One instance of `addslashes()` will be undone by one instance of `stripslashes()`. If `addslashes()` is being called more than once (I don't know why you would ever do that), then you will need to call `stripslashes()` the same number of times. It looks like you're calling `addslashes()` 3 times based on the number of slashes there are.

Comment: Hm, i only use the function one time. Think i must really go over my code. Thank you very much :)

Comment: How are you inserting the values into the database?